# PowerShell Regex replace produces empty output

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

I am trying to match the following string and replace it with the first capture goup: PCUNIT020\Username;
I need just the **Username** portion. I use the following regex:

```
 $name="PCUNIT020\Username";
 $regex="^\w+\\(.*)";
 $newname=$name -replace $regex, $1;
 $newname;
```

The shell does not output anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you have to put `$1` in quotes: `'$1'`. Otherwise it just replaces everything with the value of the variable `$1` which is not set thus with nothing.

However, instead of replacing it with the first capture group just replace everything until and including the backslash with nothing:

```
$name -replace '^\w+\\'
```